# How to find "errors" in a list of number

Tags: python, algorithm, list, recursion

For a project I'm working on, I have to find the *errors* in a list of number. An element is an error when it appears after an element with a different value.

```
# Errors are indicated by a ^
l1 = [0,0,0,0,2,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]
                      ^
l2 = [2,2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,3,3,2,3]
                        ^         ^
```

Notice in `l1` the last zeros are not errors because we assume the list like a circle, they are next to the first zeros.

I tried to implement a recursive function to do that, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
def Checkinter(testlist1):

    testlist = list(testlist1)
    print(len(testlist))

    if len(testlist) > 2:
        if testlist[0] not in boundaries:
            boundaries.append(testlist[0])
        if testlist[0] != boundaries[-1]:
            print('error')
        if len(testlist) == 3 and (testlist[0] == testlist[1] == testlist[2]):
            return None
        if testlist[0] == testlist[-1] and len(testlist) > 3:     
            del testlist[-1]
            Checkinter(testlist)
        if testlist[0] != testlist[-1]:
            del testlist[0]
            print(testlist)

        Checkinter(testlist)
```

Do you know an efficient way to do that ? Thank you.

Comment: As I understand "an element is an error when it appears after an element with a different value" would mean that the first 2, first 1 and fourth 1 are also errors. Is that the case?

Comment: Can you provide more example and specify which element is error?

Comment: No, because i forgot to mentionned that once we have detected the "boudaries" of zeros, we delete them and do the operation again

Comment: Yes sure. In the list l= ( 2,2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,3,3,2,3), the erros are the fourth 1, and the third 2

Comment: I still do not understand why the 2 is not considered wrong -- there's no other 2's in the rest of the list.

Comment: If you were talking about the first list, the 2 is not an error, because this is the first time it appears in the list

Comment: It is clear that your description of the problem is not complete, as you keep adding requirements in the comments. As of now, it's impossible to answer the question without guessing what you're trying to accomplish. Please think through the problem, and update the question accordingly.

Comment: I suggest that you turn off your computer and get a piece of paper or pencil. Now describe the steps you need to take to solve the problem **in words**. Pretend you are the computer. What steps do you need to follow to solve the problem?

Comment: Do you want the list of errors or the first error?

Comment: The list of erros. besides, your code is in Python 2 as I see izip from itertools, but im in python 3.. edit : ok i just have to use zip() instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_errors_index(lst):
  # Delete the right element equals to left so we avoid reporting errors
  # due to cyclic values
  while lst and lst[-1] == lst[0]:
    lst.pop()
  if not lst:
    return []

  # We need to keep track of 2 indexes:
  #  - the real index, which is the index of the element in the initial
  #    iterator, used to report the erroneous indexes
  #  - the last correct index, that assumes the error did not exist
  last_indexes, errors = {}, []
  correct_index = 0

  for real_index, value in enumerate(lst):
    last_seen_index = last_indexes.get(value)
    if last_seen_index is not None and last_seen_index != correct_index:
      errors.append(real_index)
    else:
      correct_index += 1
      last_indexes[value] = correct_index

  return errors


print get_errors_index([0,0,0,0,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,0,0,0])  # [8]
print get_errors_index([0,0,0,0,2,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0])  # [8]
print get_errors_index([0,0,0,0,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0])  # []
print get_errors_index([0,0,0,0,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1])  # []
print get_errors_index([0,0,0,0,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,1])  # [6, 9]
print get_errors_index([0,0,0,0,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,0,0])  # [6, 9]
print get_errors_index([0,0,0,0,0,0])  # []
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. Im going to take a look on it right now

Comment: It seems to work, but if there is more than 1 error in the list, that cant detect the other one

Comment: This is not correct. OP's definition of the amount of errors *n* is equal to *n = {all elements `i` in a list x for which `i-1` != `i`} × 2*. Your implementation assumes *n = {all elements `i` in a list x for which `i-1` != `i`}*, because your code does not take into consideration the fact that a unique element *j* is by definition preceded by and followed by a unique element (even in case *`j-1` = `j+1` != `j`*).

Comment: @Coal_ Please tell me if I am wrong: my last algorithm could reports 2 times errors (such as `[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]` could report indexes 2 and 3). This is what I fixed.
@PythonItsLife a list is now returned

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, please consider accepting it :)